# Write all bits in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file, io

How can i write all bits of a file using c#?
For example writing 0 to all bits

Please provide me with a sample

Comment: I would use a utility instead ... why do you need it?

Comment: Smells like homework....

Comment: Does anyone give C# homework?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What *exactly* are you trying to write. Also if this is homework, I'll still answer it but add the homework tag.

Comment: 14 and from Iran so you can probably forgive him if the profile isn't fake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say write all bits to a file I'll assume you mean bits as in nyble, bit, byte. That's just writing an integer to a file. You can't have a 4 bit file as far as I know so the smallest denomination will be a byte.

You probably don't want to be responsible for serializing yourself, so your easiest option would be to use the [BinaryReader and BinaryWriter classes](http://shrinkrays.net/articles/inside-system-io/part-3.aspx), and then manipulate the bits inside your C#.

The `BinaryWriter` class uses a 4 byte integer as minimum however. For example

```
writer.Write( 1 ); // 01  
writer.Write( 10 ); // 0a  
writer.Write( 100 ); // 64  
writer.Write( 1000 ); // 3e8  
writer.Write( 10000 ); // 2710  
//writer.Write( 123456789 ); // 75BCD15
```

is written to file as

```
01 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 64 00 00 00 e8 03 00 00 10 27 00 00 15 cd 5b 07
```

Comment: +/-0: For clarity, the choice should always be `File.ReadAllText`/`ReadAllBytes`/`ReadAllLines` and the `WriteAll*` complements, and only use the `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` if you have a more complicated case that prevents the simple versions.

Comment: Unless you want a smaller filesize and don't want to write your own formatter. For example 1000 is 4 bytes in a text file, 2 with the `BinaryWriter`. `BinaryWriter` is also used heavily by binary serialization.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but this will overwrite a file with data that is the same length but contains byte values of zero:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, new byte[new FileInfo(filePath).Length]);
```

Comment: What happens if the file is enormous?

Comment: @Zakalwe - it needs virtual memory equal to the file size. So for very large files, compile in 64-bit mode! :)

Comment: @Earwicker: Or use buffering!

Comment: @Zakalwe - hmm, that was intended as a joke. Serious answer: if you know that every bit in a terabyte is zero, why would you need to actually store them in the first place?

Comment: @Earwicker: Yeah your comment had me scratching my head a bit! I don't know, though; just sticking the question's spec :P

Answer (score 2):

Definitely has the foul stench of homework to it.

Hint - Think why someone might want to do this. Just deleting the file and replacing with a file of 0s of the correct length might not be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`System.IO.FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx); you'll need to open a writable stream for the file you're interested in and then write however many bytes (with value 0 in your example) to it as there are in the file already (which you can ascertain via `FileInfo.Length`). Be sure to dispose of the stream once you're done with it – `using` constructs are useful for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) available in the .NET framework

```
using(BinaryWriter binWriter =
            new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            binWriter.Write("Hello world");

        }
```

Comment: -1: Use `File.WriteAllText` (with encoding) or `File.WriteAllBytes` in place of this type of code.

Comment: For strings it is slightly pointless as BinaryWriter uses 2 bytes per character as it's encoding Unicode. However this matches the question title so +1'd you

Answer (score 0):

read into a byte and then test against >= powers of 2 to get each of the bits in that byte

Comment: I believe he wants to set all bits of a file to 0, not read them.